# USB cable connector

Tags: hardware

The arduino has a USB port which can connect to a computer.  The cable used to make this connection has a standard USB connector at one end (that connects to the computer) and a "larger" connector on the opposite end (that connects to the arduino).  See picture below:

[image]

What is the name of this "larger" connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both standard USB. The end which goes into the computer is type A (or USB-A), and the end which goes into the Arduino is type B (or USB-B). The USB-B connector is also commonly used on devices such as printers and scanners. The distinction mainly exists so it's obvious which device is the host (i.e. the computer) and which device is the client (i.e. the Arduino).

As a side note, other types of USB connector exist as well. You will probably be familiar with mini and micro USB connectors, which can be found on various devices such as digital cameras and mobile phones.

Comment: No.  The larger connectors exist for legacy reasons, not for power handling.  High-power peripherals are not powered by the USB, but by external supplies.  Meanwhile micro-USB connectors are routinely used by dedicated chargers to charge mobile devices at currents exceeding what full-size legacy USB ports are specified to supply.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Thanks for the correction. I must have been thinking of a different standard.